# Why Post Request Body is Empty? Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm creating a adduser and delete user functionality using express in nodejs. I have users.json file for storing all the users. consider the following code.

```js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var fs = require("fs");

//list users 
app.get('/listUsers', function(req, res) {
    fs.readFile(__dirname + "/" + "users.json", 'utf8', function(err, data) {
        console.log('List users ');
        res.send(data);
    });
})

//add user
app.post('/addUser', function(req, res) {
    // First read existing users.
    console.log('adding a new user');

    console.log(req.body);
    // fs.readFile(__dirname + "/" + "users.json", 'utf8', function(err, data) {
    //     data = JSON.parse(data);
    //     new_ = req.body;
    //     console.log(new_);
    //     // data["user4"] = new_["user"];
    //     // console.log(data);
    //     console.log('adding a new user')
    //     res.send(JSON.stringify(data));
    // });
})

//show user
app.get('/:id', function(req, res) {
    // First read existing users.
    fs.readFile(__dirname + "/" + "users.json", 'utf8', function(err, data) {
        var users = JSON.parse(data);
        console.log('show user ')
        var user = users["user" + req.params.id]
            // console.log(user);

        res.send(JSON.stringify(user));
    });
})

//delete user
app.delete('/deleteUser', function(req, res) {
    // First read existing users.
    fs.readFile(__dirname + "/" + "users.json", 'utf8', function(err, data) {
        data = JSON.parse(data);
        delete data["user" + req.params.id];
        console.log('deleting a user ');
        // console.log(data);
        res.send('user deleted');
    });
})


var server = app.listen(8081, function() {
    var host = server.address().address
    var port = server.address().port
    console.log("Example app listening at http://%s:%s", host, port)
})
```

I'm using curl to test this .

> curl localhost:8081/adduser --data '{"user":{
>         "name" : "mohit",
>         "password" : "password4",
>         "profession" : "teacher",
>         "id": 4
>      }'
>
> Which says curl: (52) Empty reply from server .

Also on the other side req.body is always empty. Please help me fix this.

Also if there is any efficient way of this operations then please let me know.

for adduser I want to add data provided by the request to users.json file 
for  deleteuser I want to delete the user in which the id matches from the request.

thanks. ✌️

Comment: Try `curl localhost:8081/addUser …` (with uppercase `U`) instead. Also use `--data-raw` and `-H "Content-Type: application/json"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to parse the body.
Try adding `app.use(express.json())`

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var fs = require("fs");

app.use(express.json());
```

If you use an older express version below 4.16 then use body parser

Install it:

```
npm i body-parser
```

Use it:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var fs = require("fs");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");

app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

Comment: how do I add and delete new user ? can you tell ? Should I use fs.appendFile

Comment: i cant i dont know the context of this app

Comment: its simple it has one file called users.json when I call adduser it takes all the data put it into the users.json file and the deleteuser deletes the user in which the id id specified in the request